# Specify a fields datatype while creating a new field in geodataframe with expression?

Tags: python, geopandas

I would like to know how to set the field type of `['denominator']` in a geodataframe manually in this expression to "String":

```
geo_df['denominator'] = df[["basalareap","basalareas","basalaread"]].sum(axis=1)
```

Where the fields "basalareap","basalareas","basalaread" contain floating point numbers

Automatic it assign the data-type "Double" (when check in QGIS), I tried to add the datatype in the first bracket, `geo_df['denominator', type= "String"]` but this throws an error.

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

Not really GIS related, but you can use the [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) method:

```py
geo_df['denominator'] = df[["basalareap","basalareas","basalaread"]].sum(axis=1).astype(str)
```